# How to write to multidimensional array from nested loop in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm new to C#. I write a code in Unity, which create multiple(9, 3x3) cubes and I use 3 nested fori loops.
When cubes are created, I need to save theirs ID, x, y, z, position in array. I try  and tray and can't 
find out how to save this values to array. Can someone help me with this?
Thanks and have a nice day.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MakeCube01 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cublet;

    public int cubeID = 0;
    int rowNum = 3; //x
    int columnNum = 3; //y
    int layerNum = 3; //z
    int numberOfCubes;
    //int structureDimension = 3;
    public int[,] cubeStartPositions; 

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        numberOfCubes = rowNum * columnNum * layerNum;
        cubeStartPositions = new int[numberOfCubes, 4];   //row cube, column ID,x,y,z
        for (int startX = 0; startX < rowNum; startX++)
        {
            for (int startY = 0; startY < columnNum; startY++)
            {
                for (int startZ = 0; startZ < layerNum; startZ++)
                {
                    Instantiate(cublet, new Vector3(startX, startY, startZ), new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0));

                    //write in array cubeId, x, y, z.
                    cubeStartPositions =    //????

                    Debug.Log("number of cubes:" + numberOfCubes + " ID:" + cubeID + " x:" + startX + " y:" + startY + " z:" + startZ);
                    cubeID++;
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Your array is 2-dimensional. What do you want with 3 indices?

Comment: Thanks it works fine, slightly different than in Java. Thank you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You want an array that has three dimensions, but you have only defined it with two.
You need to define your array like this, with two commas (separating 3 indexes):

```
public int[,,] cubeStartPositions;
```

Then initialise it like this

```
cubeStartPositions = new int[x, y, z];
```

Comment: And assign values like this: `cubeStartPositions[x,y,z] = foobar;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 3 dimensional array instead of 2 new int[x,y,z]

Comment: Thanks it works fine, slightly different than in Java. Thank you and have a nice day.